Running .net app on new server: You must install or update .NET to run this application
Having problems getting our .net 7 apps to run on a new Windows 2022 server.   Installing exactly what MS says here does NOT solve the issue.  I know people have asked this a million times, and  I know I've gotten it to work on servers a dozen times over the years but damnit, every time we get this message, do the download and install and it does NOT solve the problem.
Any ideas?
C:\dimension\auth_service> .\auth_service.exe
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: C:\dimension\auth_service\auth_service.exe
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\



The following frameworks were found:
  8.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10

Here is the dialog of me installing it successfully:

And here is it not showing in the SDK list, yet re-installing claims it is already there!


You've installed a runtime, not an SDK. What does dotnet --list-runtimes show? It looks like you've installed the Desktop runtime rather than the ASP.NET Core runtime...

In addition: Make sure that the runtime is installed/available for the user, which should execute your application

The error's link downloads the ASP.NET Core runtime, NOT the desktop runtime shown in the pictures. Have you tried using the error's link as is, instead of searching and downloading something else?

Besides, if you don't want to install the runtime you can create a self-contained deployment

hmm, could not get .net 7, so changed the app to .net 8, then updated the app config and it worked.  I really don't like that the thing it tells you to download does not take to you the thing that you need to download and install.  very annoying.
